Python Azure Function in Vnet not being triggered by msq in a Storage Queue
I have an issue in Azure where an Azure Function with a version 2 function listening to a Storage Queue trigger is not being triggered when a message is placed on the Storage Queue. Both the Azure Function and the Storage Account are in a VNet, so they should be able to communicate. However, I am unable to see certain settings that I should be able to enable, such as Runtime Scale Monitoring, which is necessary for Virtual Network triggers (non-HTTP).
I understand that for using triggers in a system where everything is in a VNet, Runtime Scale Monitoring needs to be enabled or Target Based Scaling needs to be set up. I am trying to determine why the function is not being triggered by a message placed on the Storage Queue.
I read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-portal#virtual-network-triggers-non-http
This is what I see in my function app:

Versus what I need to see according the documentation:

How can I get the function which is correctly configured to be triggered by a message on a queue, to be triggered?

I have followed below steps to connect Azure function app with storage account by integrating with virtual network.

Created a Python Azure functionapp with Premium Plan along with new storage account.
Configured function App with Virtual network and selected Enable network from selected networks.




Configured Storage account with virtual network and Enabled network access from selected networks.


Application settings of functionapp:

Add the storage connection string as a value of AzureWebJobsStorage.



Able to connect the storage account with function app and run the Queue triggered function.

Adding message to the queue.

Function App logs:

References:
Azure Functions networking options
